# при сборке pyinstaller'ом не включается в exe необходимые модули

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller

проблема возникла после перехода на PyCharm
запускаю скрипт в PyCharm- всё работает. собираю в exe Pyinstaller'ом- нехватает модулей. модули уже ставил и в venv Pycharm (в терминале), и в cmd от юзера, и в cmd от админа- ничего не помогает! в чем может быть загвоздка и где я еще модули недоустанавливал?

Comment: Каких модулей не хватает? Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: не хватает например beautifulsoup, но я думаю могут быть и другие. exe собирается норм, но при запуске выдает no module named bs4 итп